# is it possible to restart execution machine while jenkins job is in progress?

Tags: python, windows, jenkins

I have test case1 which needs restart machine then test case2.
I want to run testcase1 and testcase2 in a jenkins job.

If I run then them in sequence, jenkins slave goes down

How should I run them in sequence in one job

Comment: You really haven't offered much specific information here, so my answer is to the general question . . . there might be a better answer to your specific situation.  In the general case, a slave might be running multiple jobs, so you cannot just restart a slave at will.  Yeah, you can limit a slave to a single executor, but that kind of misses the point, the slave is running the job, it isn't meant to restart.  I would typically have the slave rsh (or whatever) into the target machine so the target machine can restart without restarting the slave.

Comment: If the target machine can be restarted on which slave is running without restarting the slave, that actually solves my purpose